# Django model iterator

Tags: python, django, class, magic-methods

I have a pretty fundamental question about Django models. I have a model for clinic patients (inherits from models.Model) that consists of charfields, integerfields, one textfield, and one emailfield. The types associated with these fields are limited to ASCII characters (I think) so I don't believe any low-level redefinition *SHOULD* be necessary. Say, though, that I have a Patient object x. I want to be able to iterate through the various fields in that object and print the corresponding values to a template. I specifically do NOT want to hardcode the value/field names as I have been doing so far in case the model itself is altered later on. Example ->

```
{% for value in x %}
<p> {{ value }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

I understand that, as with almost any custom class, I must write an __ **iter** __ method to detail how to iterate through this Patient object. I do not know how to write this method. I do not know if I also need to write a __ **next** __ method. My attempts at creating something like this have been met with discouraging, almost disparaging errors. Please, help :)

Comment: Could you share your `__init__` method?  How are you storing the values? You probably don't want a [`__next__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) method, as those are part of the iterator protocol, not the iterable protocol

Answer (score 0):

You only have to write the `__iter__` method. In your case i would write a custom method that does this for you instead of modifying the `__iter__` magic method. Introducing this change into your django models will be confusing since it's not the expected behavior. Go for something like `iter_fields()`. Check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_field) doc to see how to retrieve the model fields